# How to edit page heading in wordpress admin panel?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am making a plugin for custom wordpress admin panel theme, I have changed most of the things as per my requirement using hooks but I am unable to change Page Heading in Admin Panel in wordpress.

Comment: What do you refer as "page heading"? Please, add more technical details (HTML markup, PHP hooks, snapshots).

Comment: in wordpress dasboard latest version 3.1, in each page we get a heading in top of the page, like Plugins in plugins page, Users in users page. This comes vis PHP hook in wordpress, i want to change this.  thanks for the reply...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying this, this is working fine for me, anyone having better solution

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_post_to_article1' );
add_filter( 'ngettext', 'change_post_to_article1' );
function change_post_to_article1( $translated ) 
{  
   $translated = str_replace( 'Users', 'Customers', $translated );
   $translated = str_replace( 'Add New User', 'Add New Customer', $translated );
   return $translated;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how is your Admin Panel, but you can try this

```
array( "name" => "Heading",
    "desc" => "Select heading style",
    "id" => $shortname."_style",
    "type" => "select",
    "options" => array("heading.css", "heading2.css"),
    "std" => ""),
```

Where heading.css is your setting file. In this case you have a special css file ore more, where you can setup your heading.

Tell me if is ok!

Comment: thanks for reply.. its wordpress dashboard admin panel latest version 3.1, where should i write this code??

Comment: I am using this solution, any one having better solution.

Comment: YOu can use this code only if you are developing a custom Admin panel for your theme. Later today,  i will wright a tutorial about How to create a Theme Admin Panel.

Comment: Yes i am creating a theme for admin panel.

Comment: In, about 2 hours for now i will publish the tutorial.

Comment: sure, Please also forward me link.

Answer (score 0):

Like i said, creating a Wordpres Theme Admin Panel it's not so easy, but they are a lot of tutorials on internet. After a few days of searching i finally created the theme admin panel.

I will share this:

http://5wpthemes.com/blog/how-to-create-a-wordpress-theme-admin-panel/